# Calculate conditional expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have jointly distributed random variables such that $Y|X\sim Fs(X)$ (where First success distribution $Fs(p)$ is $p(k)=p(1-p)^{k−1}$) and $f_X(x)=3x^2, 0\leq x \leq 1$ and want to calculate $E(Y)$ and $Var(Y)$.

I try $E(X)=\int^1_0 x 3x^2 dx=3/4$. Since the expected value of $Fs(x)$ is $\frac 1x$ I get $E(Y)=4/3$, which is not a correct answer according to the book.

Calculating the variance I use the formula $Var(Y)=E(Var(Y|X))+Var(E(Y|X))$. The variance of $Y|X$ is (from table) $\frac{1-x}{x^2}$, so I get $E(Var(Y|X))=\frac{1/4}{9/16}=\frac 49$. $E(Y|X)$ as a function of $x$ is $\frac 1x$, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around these concepts. If I'm right this far, how do I calculate $Var(\frac 1x)$?

Comment: It's unclear what $Y|X=x \in Fs(x)$ means.

Comment: Sorry, "First success distribution" defined in the book, will edit.

Comment: Your "first success distribution" IS the geometric distribution which is related to the first success of the repeated *Bernoulli*.

Comment: In my book they are both defined and the probability function of the Geometric distribution is pq^(k)

Comment: There are two distributions commonly named Geometric.  One is the distribution of the count the *failures before* the first success: $P(F=k)= p(1-p)^k\;[k\in\{0,1,\ldots\}]$.  The other is the distribution of the count of *trials until* the first success - this is your "First success" distribution: $P(T=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}\;[k\in\{1,2,\ldots\}]$ .

Answer (score 1):

Use $E(Y)=E(E(Y|X))=E(E(Fs(X)))=E(1/X)$

$Var(Y)=E(Var(Y|X))+Var(E(Y|X))=E((1-X)/X^2)+Var(1/X)$.

Where $Var(Z)=E(Z^2)-E(Z)^2$ and $E(g(X))=\int g(x)f_X(x)dx$

Comment: Thanks! This is what I did for E(Y) and got 4/3, since E(X) is 3/4 (right???) but the book says the answer is 2/3.

Comment: For $E(Y)$ you did $1/E(X)$. That's incorrect. You need $E(1/X)$. Order of operation matters. Look into the first line of the answer to understand the correct order.

Comment: Thank you, this course is screwing with my head so much, I'll read up.

Comment: Many things are falling into place, thanks for getting me started on the path to knowledge =)